# Can I run a tool like Nmap from a remote machine to pentest on my local Network?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, local, remote-connection, nmap

Can I set up a backtrack system at home to connect to and remotely use tools like nmap on whatever network I'm in locally?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

- Arrange for remote access to your home system. Obviously this depends on O/S.

  - For Linux at home I would use SSH.

    - set port forwarding on your home router.
    - set up SSH service on home PC.
    - set up SSH client at local network (e.g. Putty).
- Ensure nothing in your home network and ISP blocks any outgoing connections.
- Make sure you have written permission from local management.
- Connect to home PC and run nmap on your home PC.

Comment: To be clear, i'm looking to capture and ping on my laptop wifi card and pipe the data back to a server running remotely. Is this what you were describing?

Comment: @November: If by "piping" you mean using STDOUT piped across a network connection, that isn't in your original question. That can be achieved [using SSH](http://linux.icydog.net/ssh/piping.php) or with something like rsh/rcmd. None of this is necessary if you just want to view what nmap reports.